# Gradle - how do I know which plugin is a specific task introduced from?

Tags: gradle

I'm new to Gradle, as I'm reading the build scripts inside a large multi-project, I want to know which task is being introduced from which plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there is no easy plugin --> task reference.

If you use:

```
gradle help --task <task name>
```

You can see the type used to create the task. This could be useful for custom plugins where you have access to the source.

If you're wondering about the built-in Gradle plugins, your best bet is the [User's Guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html). For example, [this section](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_tasks) shows all of the tasks provided by the Java plugin.